# Update the column based on

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

Please help me with the below :

The table AR_X_LO is a SCD TYPE 2 table. There was a bug in the ETL with the result that changed records has not been end dated, e.g.

```
AR_X_LO_TP_ID AR_ID    EFF_TMS            LO_ID    RANK END_TMS    ORIG_SRC_STM_ID RT_TMS   
------------- ------- ------------------- -------- ---- ---------- --------------- ----------                    
802           6751231 2016-06-08 00:00:00 39748325    1 NULL       9643         2016-06-09             
802           6751231 2015-05-02 00:00:00 29496916    1 NULL       9643         2015-05-04
```

The ETL was supposed to end the changed row with the EFF_TMS of the new row - 1 day.

```
AR_X_LO_TP_ID AR_ID    EFF_TMS            LO_ID    RANK END_TMS    ORIG_SRC_STM_ID RT_TMS   
------------- ------- ------------------- -------- ---- ---------- --------------- ----------                    
802           6751231 2016-06-08          39748325    1 NULL                9643   2016-06-09             
802           6751231 2015-05-02          29496916    1 2016-06-07          9643   2015-05-04
```

I want to write a SQL query that for each AR_ID, AR_X_LO_TP_ID, RANK, ORIG_SRC_STM_ID combination returns what the END_TMS was supposed to be.

Comment: Do you just want a query (SELECT?) or an update?

Comment: Please explain why sas and oracle are tagged. Do you run a SAS program connected to an Oracle database backend? Do you require a `proc sql` solution?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far as well. Also, depending on the 'bug' maybe you can fix it within the process.

Answer (score 0):

According to your request being for

> "a SQL query that [...] returns what the END_TMS was supposed to be"

and since you specified the SAS tag, the following SAS code will do just that:

```
proc sql;
create table result as
select t1.*, datepart(t2.EFF_TMS)-1 as END_TMS format=E8601DA.
from AR_X_LO(drop=END_TMS) t1
left join AR_X_LO t2
    on t1.AR_ID = t2.AR_ID
    and t1.AR_X_LO_TP_ID = t2.AR_X_LO_TP_ID
    and t1.RANK= t2.RANK
    and t1.ORIG_SRC_STM_ID = t2.ORIG_SRC_STM_ID
    and t1.EFF_TMS < t2.EFF_TMS
group by t1.EFF_TMS
having END_TMS=min(END_TMS)
;
quit;
```

Be aware that this code contains SAS-specific statements/functions (like the `datepart()`  function, `format=` statement or the `drop=` dataset option) which will not work in other SQL environments (like Oracle which you also tagged) and will perform poorly in SAS if indeed you are working on an Oracle backend.
If the latter is true, you could probably do this more elegantly with analytic functions such as `lag`, `lead`, `partition by`, etc (using SQL-passthrough when within SAS)

NOTE: conforming to your provided example of the expected result, I returned the END_TMS as date even though the name of that variable suggest it should probably by a timestamp (datetime in SAS).